# Theme files and imagesnot loading on a mobile device

Tags: images, themes, errors, css, mobile

I am just setting up my site but I have run in to a weird issue where the site seems to load perfectly fine on my computer but when I view it on a mobile device (iPhone/iPad) it appears to have none of the template files and none of the images are attached to posts etc.

Any thoughts what could be wrong?

I might add incase it helps I built this on a local set up and it's my first time using this process so there may be something in that I did wrong. But I checked the uploads folder and themes folder and they both have '755' permissions.

This is the site:
http://www.phoebeschoppingblock.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem.

Turns out when switching my site over from local to live I missed a few links in the DB (I did run a script to check but it obviously didn't pick up all the links). So simple fix corrected the links and the site works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `localhost` in the settings at `wp-admin -> Settings -> general`. That literally means "this computer"-- the computer requesting the web site. It only works if the browser viewing the site is on the same computer as the web server serving the site.

You have to use your domain or a static IP. In your case, `http://www.phoebeschoppingblock.com`.

Comment: I didn't use it in the settings. I know you can't do that lol. But I did miss a few links in the DB when switching over.